# How to add admin notices on Woocommerce Order edit page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to trigger a notice on order edit page of WooCoommerce.

I believe I have to use the [WC_Admin_notices](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Admin_Notices.html) class, but I don't know how to use it.

I tried

```
$adminnotice = new WC_Admin_Notices();
$adminnotice->add_notice("something");
```

Comment: Hiya - how are you firing it? In which hook?

Comment: @Frits inside `
add_action('completed_shop_order', 'ggoowlccpy_gateway_init');
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'ggoowlccpy_gateway_init');

function ggoowlccpy_gateway_init()
{
    class Ggowl_CCPY extends WC_Payment_Gateway_CC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the built-in wordpress `admin_notices` hook to insert your own, like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_order_edit_notice' );
function my_order_edit_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice is-dismissible notice-info"> <!-- can use 'notice-error' or 'notice-success' as well -->
        <p><?php _e( 'Here be dragons!', 'text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

You can always add to the query to nail down where/when the admin notice shows inside the function itself, for example:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_order_edit_notice' );
function my_order_edit_notice() {
    if(get_post_type() != 'shop_order') { return; } //only show on 'order' pages
    ?>
    <div class="notice is-dismissible notice-info">
        <p><?php _e( 'Here be dragons!', 'text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the correct answer but the code below worked for me.

```
$adminnotice = new WC_Admin_Notices();
$adminnotice->add_custom_notice("Hello","<div>Error</div>");
$adminnotice->output_custom_notices();
```